# Python GmailAPI OAuth2 issue when it asks to go to a URL on a SSH server connection

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-api, gmail-api

i'm using the default how to from google to set up Gmail API...

I've set up an oAuth2 key in the console and when I run the python script it

When I run the code in a terminal I get the URL which I copy into my web browser on a local machine.
I get to the oAuth screen and approve the application.

It then redirects to localhost:13949 and says there is no web page there. The python script just hangs out there as if nothing has happened.

I'm not sure how to get around this.

````
    """Shows basic usage of the Gmail API.
    Lists the user's Gmail labels.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)```
````

Comment: What do you have as your redirect URIs in your `credentials.json` file? Have you tried redownloading your credentials and running again? Also, have you installed all the necessary packages? (run `pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client google-auth-httplib2 google-auth-oauthlib`)?

Comment: Same issue here. @RafaGuillermo, yes, I tried redownloading (even creating new ones for gmail and others api like Drive) and also reinstall the client. Same result the BostonMacOSX describes. Any idea?